# Is it possible to recover a deleted gist on Github?

Tags: github, gist

I created a a gist on Github and then created a new one after making changes in it. But I accidently deleted the updated one. So I wanted to know if it's possible to recover it. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Have you tried contacting GitHub support?

Comment: @John Doe – Did Github support help you recover a Gist? I'm in the same boat and would love an answer..

Answer (score 9):

Go to github contact page [here](https://github.com/contact) and email them saying you need to recover your deleted gist and also mention the link or the description of the deleted gist.They will recover it for you.

Comment: have you tried this before? I've also deleted some Gists by accident and was wondering if they can help to recover it.

Comment: It has been long I posted this but I think I was able to recover the deleted gist successfully. It is just that the github guys need some reference to the gist.

Comment: how would you have a reference if you deleted quite few? Is there a way to do it without?

Answer (score 4):

I just successfully had a gist undeleted.

You will need to contact support: https://support.github.com/contact?tags=rr-restore

- **Subject:** Undelete A Gist
- **Body:** For best results, write them a nice note, include the link to the gist you deleted.

They undeleted mine within like 10 minutes of submission, though it states it can take up to 5 days.

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me. But I got the reply back in 6 hours and you do not even need to provide the link of the gist 